Issues for DSV3 DSMC software from Bird
I'm trying to simulate a Cubesat, by simulating through DSMC DSV3 in order to get the drag coefficient, fonction of altitude and AoA.
Very few examples are avalaible on Bird's website. My main issue Comes from the DSVDT.DAT creation, which doesn't work. I'm using rhino 3D to export a raw file, in order to use dsv3g, and get the first file.
Does anyone know this software and could help ? I'll provide more details
Thank you,
